# Maximum subarray problem - min value solution?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

Have you ever felt like your head wasn't meant for an algorithm?

I tried solving the [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and I came across this solution on Codewars:

```js
var maxSequence = function(arr){
  var min = 0, ans = 0, i, sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    sum += arr[i];
    min = Math.min(sum, min);
    ans = Math.max(ans, sum - min);
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log(maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, -4]));
```

I understand how to solve this problem with a linear time complexity using `Kadane's algorithm`:

```js
var maxSequence = function(arr){
  let max = 0;
  let localMax = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    localMax = Math.max(localMax + arr[i], arr[i]);
    max = Math.max(localMax, max);
  }

  return max;
}

console.log(maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, -4]));
```

But I can't make sense of why the first solution works. I simply can't grasp the idea behind it. I feel like a need a little help getting over the hump.

Edit: Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/florianmartens/pen/zYoWwVX?editors=1010) with some examples

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain what the "Maximum subarray problem" is

Comment: The explanation should be **here**, as part of your question. This site should not require an external source.

Comment: do you have some examples with result?

Comment: I added a Codepen link

Comment: passed 40 tested failed 14.. still trying...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm you provided is doing the same thing, in a more complex manner though. *In order to explain it properly, I will compare the **Codewars algorithm** you provided with the **Kadanes algorithm** in various steps of their execution.*

---

Let us consider the array:

```
[2 -4 3 2 6 -10 -12 20]
```

Here is the *Codewars algorithm* you provided:

```
var maxSequence = function(arr){
    var min = 0, ans = 0, i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
        min = Math.min(sum, min);
        ans = Math.max(ans, sum - min);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Here is the implementation of *Kadanes algorithm* mentioned in Wikipedia:

```
def max_subarray(numbers):
"""Find the largest sum of any contiguous subarray."""
best_sum = 0  # or: float('-inf')
current_sum = 0
for x in numbers:
    current_sum = max(0, current_sum + x)
    best_sum = max(best_sum, current_sum)
return best_sum
```

---

*First step:-*

`sum` **changes to** 2 and `min` *remains the same*. The `ans` ***changes to*** 2.

*Second step:-*

`sum` **changes to** -2 and `min` **changes to** -2. The `ans` *is still* 2. An interesting thing to notice here, according the implementation of Kadanes algorithm by Wikipedia, there in the second stage the value of `current_sum` will **change** to 0 which is the correct way to proceed.

However in the codewars implementation, the value of `sum` *is still* -2. If you notice a little more carefully though, you will observe that the value of `sum-min` is 0 in the codewars implementation. This is a really important point to notice. *Instead of changing sum to 0 when its value reaches less than 0. We **store the minimum number that must be substracted from sum to make the net sum 0.** This value is stored in `min` and which also explains why it is named so.*

Here is a record of the value of variables so far:

```
 sum    min    ans
  2      0      2     //ans = max(0, 2-0)
 -2     -2      2     //ans = max(2, -2+2)
```

*Third step:-*

The `sum` **changes to** 1. `min` *still remains the same*. The ans **changes to** 3 which is the correct. How did this happen though?

In the Kadanes algorithm, you change the value of `current_sum` to 3 at this stage. In the codewars implementation, instead of changing `sum` to 3, what they have done is used a *min variable which I repeat again stores the number that should be substracted from answer so that we obtain the same value as we do in current_sum.* This is more clear from this part of the algorithm.

```
ans = Math.max(ans, sum - min);   //sum-min is current_max
```

Here when we substract the `min` from your `sum`. *It neutralizes that extra negative in your answer.* In this array A, the extra negative is `2 + (-4) = -2`. In each of the following steps, we will observe that here *sum is **not** containing the maximum continuous subarray sum. **Maximum continuous subarray sum there is stored in sum - min.*** This is the key of this algorithm. *sum-min is the current_sum here*. Here are the following steps:

```
sum    min    ans
 1     -2      3      //ans = max(2, 1+2)
 3     -2      5      //ans = max(3, 3+2)
 9     -2      11     //ans = max(5, 9+2)
-1     -2      11     //ans = max(11, -1+2)
```

It is interesting to observe that *even though the value of sum is negative in the last step, the value of min does not change*. Why is that? The answer is it does not need to. If you look at `sum-min` is this case, it is 1 and not less than 0. Hence *there is a possibility that if sufficient positive numbers follow after the current index in A, the value of sum-min might exceed the current value of ans.* If you dry run Kadanes algorithm till this step, you will notice that even there the value of `current_sum` will not change to 0 at this stage, it will be 1.

*Remaining steps:-*

```
sum    min    ans
-1     -2      11     //ans = max(11, -1+2)
-13    -13     11     //ans = max(11, -13+13)
 7     -13     20     //ans = max(11,  7+13)
```

The most important point in this implementation, `sum-min` here is analogous to `current_sum` of Kadanes algorithm.

---

I should also mention that the Kadanes algorithm and codewars algorithm you provided will **not** work if the *input array consists of all negative numbers*. Both are not meant for it. There is a small implementation difference in the Kadanes algorithm if you want it to work for array consisting of all negative numbers (initialize current_sum to `A[0]`).

*Do comment if you face any problems in understanding my explanation.*

Comment: What does the `min` signify? What is the need for `min = Math.min(sum, min);`?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire ignores negative numbers for `sum`

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I will be update my answer to explain the significance of `min` in this program in few minutes.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I have updated my answer to provide more insight on the role of `min` in the mentioned algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the the Codewars algorithm will work for every test case.

Following are the test cases where this algorithm will fail:

**Test Case 1:** arr = [-1]

**Test Case 2:** arr = [-1, -2]

For both the test cases, the algorithm under test gives an output equal to `0`, which is not the correct answer.

**PS:** I have checked the Codewars problem. The test cases for the problem are not yet **comprehensive** and this problem has issues.

So for the time being, Kadane's algorithm is a good choice to solve the problem in linear time complexity.

Comment: The implementation provided in the question *is not meant for arrays which contain all negative numbers.* Even the implementation of  `Kadanes algorithm` provided in the question will also **not** work in this case. A change in the given algorithm is required.  Here is a link to the `Kadanes algorithm`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm